# Imperative mood tenses?

Tags: tense, imperative

To my current understanding, German has three word moods and for each mood the following tenses:

1. Present
2. Present perfect
3. Simple past
4. Past perfect
5. Futur I
6. Futur II.

Since imperative is a mood, does there exist 'past' imperative? Would that ever be used? It seems a bit non intuitive to me since imperative would be like giving an immediate action. So, would it be an 'order' in the past?

Comment: I'm not convinced, that English terms (enumeration 1 through 4) are helpful in a question like this, since the terms have a similar but somewhat different meaning in English.

Comment: @guidot: I know what you mean; another problem is that grammatical terminology differs from source to source, so "simple past" for some = "preterite" for others. But I've noticed that German grammatical sources aren't always consistent either. I don't think using English grammatical terms of German is a huge problem in this case, as long as people realize that "German present" is similar to, but not quite the same as, "English present". For case names the German and English concepts are truly incompatible; I use "subject, object, possessive" for case names in English.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Grammarians call the imperative a mood, but I'm not sure that's really a helpful way to classify it. As mentioned in the comments, it does not have a tense. You can classify sentences according to various tense, mood, aspect, etc., and ask philosophical questions about whether certain combinations exist or not. But grammar is only a description of language, a theory of which combinations of words can to said in a given language. If grammar predicts combinations that aren't possible then it's grammar that's wrong, not the language. The imperative is something of an exceptional case because some combinations can't occur in practice. For example there is no first person singular imperative. I suppose you could invent one for people who like to talk to themselves, but languages tend not to have unnecessary and unhelpful features. Similarly, until someone invents a time machine, a past tense imperative doesn't seem too practical.

Answer (score 0):

There basically is just one imperative. However, if a tense if constructed using an auxiliary verb, you can technically form an imperative in that tense by applying the imperative to the auxiliary. [Wiktionary](https://de.wiktionary.org/wiki/Flexion:gehen) even lists an “Imperativ Perfekt”, but also marks it as “ungebräuchlich“. I would question the usefulness of that concept, though.

Comment: Grammis as a page on [Imperativ Perfekt und Imperativ Passiv](https://grammis.ids-mannheim.de/systematische-grammatik/4560) which seems relevant here.