# Konjugation: Konjunktiv II oder?

Tags: meaning, verb, meaning-in-context, indirect-speech

Ist der Konjunktiv II in dem folgenden Satz zutreffend verwendet ?

> Auf die Frage, wie viele Hochleistungssportler diese Tests durchgeführt hätten und ob bereits positive Befunde gäbe, bekamen wir keine Antwort.

Kann man und sollte man einem anderen Modus auswählen und warum?

Comment: Nebenbemerkung: Korrekt wäre "[...] und ob **es** bereits positive Befunde gäbe[...]"

Comment: @Hubert Schölnast: "Man kann jeden Modus mit jeder Zeit kombinieren." Außer imperativ. (Sorry, I couldn't stop myself. Besides, there was a question on that a few days ago - [here](https://german.stackexchange.com/q/69551/43989).)

Comment: @idmean Ich möchte dich dazu anregen, in Zukunft die Frage zu editieren. Ich denke, es wird als hilfreicher wahrgenommen, als ein Kommentar. Wenn man sich nicht sicher ist, was gemeint ist, bleibt natürlich nur die Nachfrage. Aber ich denke, hier ist es relativ klar.

Answer (score 2):

Einen "Subjonktive" oder Subjunktiv wie im Französischen gibt es in der deutsche Grammatik nicht, dort wird von Konjunktiv I und II gesprochen. Ich vermute, dass du den Konjunktiv II **"durchgeführt hätten"** meinst.

Man würde in der indirekten Rede, wie hier, normalerweise den Konjunktiv I verwenden.

Zum Beispiel:

> Auf die Frage, ob ein Hochleistungssportler diese Tests durchgeführt **habe** und ob es bereits positive Befunde **gebe**, bekamen wir keine Antwort.

Im Plural, wie in deinem Beispielsatz, wäre der Konjunktiv I von "haben" aber **"haben"**, und diese Form ist nicht als Konjunktiv erkennbar. In solchen Fällen kommt dann ersatzweise der Konjunktiv II zum Einsatz.

Es ist in diesem Fall für "haben" beides möglich:

Konjunktiv I, der sich aber nicht vom Indikativ unterscheidet:

> Auf die Frage, wie viele Hochleistungssportler diese Tests durchgeführt **haben**, bekamen wir keine Antwort.

Oder der klar als Konjunktiv erkennbare Konjunktiv II:

> Auf die Frage, wie viele Hochleistungssportler diese Tests durchgeführt  **hätten**, bekamen wir keine Antwort.

Für "geben" ist der Konjunktiv II "gäbe" in dem Beispielsatz nicht ganz korrekt. Es gibt keine Verwechslungsgefahr mit dem Indikativ, deshalb müsste es "gebe" (Konjunktiv I) heißen.

> Auf die Frage, wie viele Hochleistungssportler diese Tests durchgeführt hätten und ob es bereits positive Befunde gebe, bekamen wir keine Antwort.

Allerdings: der Autor/Jounalist gibt ja hier seine eigene Frage wieder. Der Konjunktiv in der indirekten Rede dient normalerweise dazu, die wiedergegebenen Worte von den eigenen unterscheidbar zu machen.

Man könnte hier m.E. auch einfach den Indikativ benutzen:

> Auf die Frage, wie viele Hochleistungssportler diese Tests durchgeführt haben und ob es bereits positive Befunde gibt, bekamen wir keine Antwort.

Comment: *Gäbe* ist Konjunktiv 2.

Comment: @DavidVogt: autsch, du hast natürlich recht, danke. Editiert.